# Effect of debug symbols in visual studio

Tags: performance, visual-studio, debug-symbols

Does enabling debug symbols in visual studio cause slowness of execution of an application ? How does enabling or disabling of these symbols affect ?

Answer (score 1):

Debugging always affect performance.

Comment: Can you please explain me a bit more?

Comment: @beginner Te answer is too broad, read here please: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know